# Trying to Create an array for user input in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Im doing an assignment where I have to get user input and put it in an array. I got to the point where the program stops after hitting the numbers user puts for Array Size. Im stuck from here. ( UI.prompt is a library from another program but theres nothing in there that can affect any code input)

```
int ArraySize = UI.PromptInt("how long do you want your array? "); //prints out ArraySize = number of ints 
int[] NA = new int[ArraySize];
//array is the max size 
int SizeCounter = 0 ;
int[] New_Array = new int [10];
for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
{
    int AddTo_NewArray = UI.PromptInt("Enter numbers for the array: ");
    foreach (int e in NA) // e is for element in an NA
    {
        SizeCounter += ArraySize;
        //int AddTo_NewArray = UI.PromptInt("Enter numbers for the array: ");
        if (e == SizeCounter)
        {
            break;
        }                    
    }                
    New_Array[i] = i;
    //Console.WriteLine(string.Join("Enterd values", New_Array));  //eliminates the system.32[] error
    Console.WriteLine("Enter values: " , New_Array );                
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `NA` *and* `New_Array`, and why is `New_Array` a fixed size instead of the size the user requests?

Comment: From all the online resource they keep showing that my array needs to be fixed before its changed. I have both variables in their to experiment what works and doesnt.

Comment: you would be better off creating something like this `object[] dynamicArray = { };` then create a `List<T>` and populate the list and then assigning the `dynamicArray = List<T>.ToArray()`  `List<T> would be your List<object>` variable declaration.. this is more dynamic than having a fixed size

Answer (score 1):

```
int ArraySize = UI.PromptInt("how long do you want your array? "); 
int[] NA = new int[ArraySize];

foreach(int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
{
    NA[i] = UI.PromptInt("Enter numbers for the array: ");
}
```

This way, an array is created with the size the user chose and a he will be prompted to enter a value until the array is filled :)

Comment: So i am doing what you told me and it works but the array I entered isn't printing the numbers

Comment: My bad i didn't know you want to print the values. You want to print the value on the console after each time the User entered one on the keyboard ? if yes just add Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value number {0} is {1}", i, NA[i]);   at the end of the foreach loop :)  if you need anything else just poke me but it should do the trick